# How to create this in modern Blender (3.0)

Tags: effects

6 years ago i created a short blender effect movie
[see youtube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPd7xdNqm28)

Now many years later i wonder how one would create it with current latest versions of Blender. I'm not sure how i made it in the past, the blend file has been lost.
It might have been torus shape or with verticles as particle alike emissions.
If i'm correctly the older versions of blender had some shader like that.

In the past it was just for fun, but in the current i like to recreate it for the full song, the song was some internet free music, i just like it. But i'm not sure how one would recreate the effect these days.

Comment: Blender three isn’t released yet, So things that are supposed to work may not. Go with the current stable version. Also, please do not use YouTube links. Use the built-in image embedding system to post screenshots of what you were trying to achieve. Using an external reference and little description leaves the user to wonder which part of the video you were trying to duplicate, and also in danger zone of accidentally going to something they did not want to see.

Comment: too much worries 
i've always used latest versions even for payed productions.
I simply dont delete old beldenr version (which one could still download anyway).

Comment: The latest released version is 2.93 **not** version 3 which isn't yet complete.

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Also use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a mix of 2 *Array* modifiers with *Object Offset*, first give your sphere object an *Array* modifier with an empty as *Object Offset*, move away the empty and make it rotate a bit:

[image]

Give it a second *Array* modifier with a second empty as *Object Offset*, move away the empty and make it rotate a bit:

[image]

Rotate the empties, move them up and down, etc...

Comment: Indeed that was it, now these days with eevee and bloom it renders super fast less then a seccond.